# Amazon RDS Mysql Instance stopped working throwing error : Unknown database

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

Before I mention the issue I want to tell some information first : 
I have hosted my Node.js App on Amazon Ec2 instance and Database is also hosted on Amazon RDS mysql instance. 
Everything was working fine I was able to store and retrieve data from my Amazon hosted database. All of sudden since this morning mysql is throwing error : 
**Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'audiodb'**

I have confirmed the database credentials and database endpoint everything seems to be fine as it was working and I havn't changed anything.

I am attaching some screenshots of error : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide connection code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have checked database is somehow deleted. in my personal openion someone has attacked mysql injection.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you are using RDS in EC2 or lambda you can use the roles and remove the public facing from internet which will not allow anyone attack from outside

If you are using on you machine then just change the inbound port for your IP.
Hope this will help you to prevent future attack

Comment: Thanks a lot I will change the security group rule now. @ChandaniPatel